# Selecting a saved card in the browser puts the expiration date in the wrong format

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, autofill

Our expiration field is expecting: "MMYY".  When you select a card saved in the browser you'll get something like: "MM/Y":

[image]

```html
<span class="font-weight-normal card-text">Expiry Date</span>
   <div class="input">
      <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
      <input type="text" class="form-control cardField" 
         placeholder="MMYY" pattern="\d{4}" maxlength="4" 
         title="Must be MMYY Format" name="Card.ExpirationDate">
   </div>
```

Removing the maxlength constraint, we get: "MM/YYYY".

**Is there a way to tell the browser how we want that date?**

I am using firefox, but obviously we'd want a solution to cover all browsers.  Is reformatting it after it changes our only solution?

We considered adding `autocomplete="off"`, but that doesn't prevent it from filling that field when you select a saved card.

Thanks!